# File wont move to the folder path I made but query sent to the database

Tags: php

I made a form called "File upload form" that form will help me to upload some files for future, since I provided some apps for people who want to use my apps. Let say I made a template of some excel files.

my directory looks like shown below:

site dir --> https://imgbbb.com/image/PsAoZ

i try to upload any file(s) from home.php (adm folder) to download (inc folder), but the file always moved to the adm folder.

## form to upload

```
<h1>Upload File</h1>
<hr>
<form class="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="kodeapl">Kode File</label>
<input type="text" name="kodeapl" class="form-control" value="adp-" autofocus required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="namafile">Nama File</label>
<input type="text" name="namafile" class="form-control" autofocus required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="linkfile">Link File</label>
<input type="file" name="linkfile" class="form-control" autofocus required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="uploader">Uploader</label>
<input type="text" name="uploader" value="<?= $_SESSION['username']?>" class="form-control" autofocus required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
</div>
<?php
```

## code to execute the form

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $tglupload = date('Y/m/d'); #uploaddate
    //credential file
    $apl = $_FILES['linkfile']['name']; #file name
    $curdir = $_FILES['linkfile']['tmp_name']; #current directory
    $path = '../inc/img/download/'; #path to save the file uploaded
    $uploadsfile = $path.basename($apl); //variable to send query to db
    move_uploaded_file($uploadsfile, $curdir);
    $uploadfile = $db->query("INSERT INTO download(kode_apl, apl, link, tglupload, uploader) VALUES('$_POST[kodeapl]','$_POST[namafile]','$uploadsfile','$tglupload','$_POST[uploader]')");
    var_dump($uploadfile);
        }
?>
```

## this result of var_dump()

```
object(PDOStatement)#2 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(152) "INSERT INTO download(kode_apl, apl, link, tglupload, uploader) VALUES('adp-01','EMPLOYEES FEE ','../inc/img/download/K13 IIS.xlsx','2019/03/23','admin')" }
```

## result query in database

result in database -> https://imgbbb.com/image/PsM7n

but i have no seen any files stored in folder path. even data fetched already in list I made when i clicked the url the page says object not found.

I am new of this, by the way.
Thanks for attention.

Comment: Open `move_uploaded_file` manual please.

Comment: `Linux` or `Windows` etc.  Any error message, etc. etc.. etc.... etc.

Comment: Storing the full path is kind of a not so good idea `../inc/img/download/K13 IIS.xlsx` if all your files go in `../inc/img/download/`  you can store just the filename and put the rest in PHP code.  The reason is if you ever migrate your server or change file structures, you'll learn what  `symlink` and `mount bind` are real fast ... because all your paths will/could be different.  It's very easy to change this in a line of code, very hard to do it to thousands of DB records.  Short term it's fine how you have it, long term not so good.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I am using Windows, by the way.